# Synchronizing a WPF ScrollViewer with a WinForms ScrollBar

Tags: wpf, winforms, binding, interop, scroll

Due to an unsolved issue in my current project [ [Weird scrollbar UI in hosted WPF composite control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870516/weird-scrollbar-ui-in-hosted-wpf-composite-control) ], I've had to defer to workarounds. One such idea I came up with was to keep the ScrollViewer in question in sync with a Windows Forms ScrollBar (horizontal and vertical). How would I go about doing that?

In essence, I want the WinForms scrollbar(s) to work like the ScrollViewers (in terms of dragging and events suchlike).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to implement it without having to much around with the WinAPI. Here's how I did it:

1. Registered a ScrollOffsetChanged event handler with the scrollviewer (the composite control that implemented the IScrollInfo interface exposed the event).
2. Registered a ValueChanged event handler with the windows forms scrollbar.
3. A couple of signal flags to prevent cyclic calls to the event handler.
4. The first handler called an UpdateExternalScrollBars() function that calculated the Maximium Scrollbar property using the following expression: ScrollViewer->ExtentHeight/Width - ScrollViewer->ViewportHeight/Width. The Value property was directly set to ScrollViewer->Vertical/HorizontalOffset.
5. The second fetched the Value property from the windows forms scrollbar and passed it to ScrolViewer->ScrollToVertial/HorizontalOffset(). The signal flags were appropriately set beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no any other way than send/listen to the lo-level API Windows messaging. You should have a decent knowledge of the Win APIs, and how to manage them. I'd add also that the scrollers are mid-complexity task to manage, but maybe it's me...

Here is the [vertical scroll message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787577%28VS.85%29.aspx) reference.

Comment: I was under the impression that WPF uses a different measurement scale than Win32/WinForms. Would you happen to know anything about that?

Comment: I didn't say that's easy. However, by peeking inside the ScrollViewer code, it seems that it uses the same APIs. In other words, the scrollbars should be always the same, regardless the top layer UI.